# Get SMTP server certificate (port 587, STARTTLS) in Visual C++

Tags: c++, ssl, visual-c++, smtp

I gather that this can be done with openssl, but is there any way to do without that?

I can get the certificate no problem if I connect to a port with implicit SSL (e.g., smtp.gmail.com, port 465) using the following code.

```
// Convert the server name to a wide string
USES_CONVERSION;
LPWSTR lpServerName = A2W(szServer);

BOOL bResults = FALSE;
HINTERNET   hSession = NULL, hConnect = NULL, hRequest = NULL;

hSession = WinHttpOpen( L"my app", 
    WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, 
    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0 );

if( hSession )
    hConnect = WinHttpConnect( hSession,  
    lpServerName,
    PortNum, 0 );

if( hConnect )
    hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, L"GET",  
    NULL,
    NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, 
    WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, 
    WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE );

if( hRequest )
    bResults = WinHttpSendRequest( hRequest,
    WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0,
    WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 
    0, 0 );

if(hRequest)
{
    // Okay, the connection and request succeeded, now try to get the certificate chain
    PCCERT_CONTEXT pCert=NULL;
    DWORD dwSize = sizeof(pCert);
    BOOL res = WinHttpQueryOption(hRequest,
        WINHTTP_OPTION_SERVER_CERT_CONTEXT,
        &pCert,
        &dwSize);   

    if (res) 
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: You answered your own question (is there a way to do it without OpenSSL? Use WinHTTP instead - though you should not being use WinHTTP for non-HTTP protocols). So, what more do you want? To get the certificate, you have to initiate an SSL/TLS handshake. If you don't use an SSL/TLS library for that, you have to implement it manually using straight socket API calls.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, sorry, I should have clarified further. The code I posted works when connecting to smtp.gmail.com:465, but WinHttpQueryOption returns an error code when connecting to smtp.gmail.com:587. It sounds like you're saying I shouldn't use WinHTTP for talking to an SMTP server, and I get that. But since it was relatively easy to use that code to get the cert chain for smtp.gmail.com:465, I was hoping there was a similarly easy way to get it for smtp.gmail.com:587.

Comment: "*The code I posted works when connecting to smtp.gmail.com:465*" - you CANNOT use the WinHTTP API for non-HTTP protocols, like SMTP. Period. The *only* reason it works in your example is because port 465 requires the SSL/TLS handshake immediately upon connect before any SMTP-related traffic can be exchanged. That is not the case on port 587. So, your approach will NOT work in a STARTTLS scenario.

Comment: You need to use an actual SMTP library (and there are plenty of them around - try libcurl, for instance), or write your own SMTP code from scratch. SMTP is not hard to implement, and you can use Microsoft's SChannel API to handle SSL/TLS over a standard Winsock socket connection.

Comment: _The only reason it works in your example is because port 465 requires the SSL/TLS handshake immediately upon connect before any SMTP-related traffic can be exchanged. That is not the case on port 587. So, your approach will NOT work in a STARTTLS scenario."_ - Okay, that helps me understand the issue better. So, WinHTTP knows how to do the SSL/TLS handshake, but it can't get through the SMTP to get to the handshake on port 587 (if I understand correctly). Looks like a library is the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [this example](http://www.coastrd.com/c-schannel-smtp) (it can be done easier these days but this should give an idea of the APIs to use).

Comment: "*So, WinHTTP knows how to do the SSL/TLS handshake*" - yes, but it is doing it on behalf of the HTTPS protocol (HTTP over SSL/TLS), not the SMTP protocol. "*it can't get through the SMTP to get to the handshake on port 587*" - no, as it doesn't implement the SMTP protocol, let alone the STARTTLS command. And as such, it can't communicate any further with the SMTP server once the SSL/TLS session has been established.

Comment: @RustyX Thanks for the link. I'm working through the handshaking with OpenSSL at the moment, but I'll definitely check out that method as well.